# can't understand how the 'lazy' works in RDD (Python)

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I know that in Pyspark, the RDD won't calculate step by step. But in this code, I found that even I used the `try1` function, nothing happended to the `d`. Then what should I do if I want to do something in the middle of the function, not only the return result of the function?

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
dt=sc.parallelize(np.array(df.T))
d=[]
def try1(x):
    d.append(1)
    return set(x)
print (dt.map(try1).collect())
print (d)
```

result:

```
[{1, 3}, {2, 4}]
[]
```

Comment: You're calling an exterior python object (on the driver) inside a pyspark `UDF` (called for every row on the slave nodes). The only action that you can have is through the returned value (`set(x)` here ). When we say Pyspark is "lazy" it means the computations will wait until  you call a writing function or bring the data to the driver.

Comment: Sorry i haven't quite understood, do you mean that my question isn't related to the 'lazy' character of RDD?    Now I want to do something when using this funcion and it is not quite convinient using the return value (actually, modifiying another df). How could I do this?    Much thanks!

Comment: Exactly, your problem isn't the "lazy" character of pyspark, sorry for being unclear. What you're doing here is appending 1 everytime the function is called so basically creating a list of ones of length the number of lines in your RDD (`dt.count()`). You can't modify a table different than the one you're working on. Can you tell us more about what you want to do ?

Comment: Oh I see. Can I say it like this: in the ```map``` of an RDD, one can only modify the RDD which is being "mapped", and we can not do things to other ones except the RDD (like the ```d``` in this example)?   Actually, I'm trying to write another RDD(or a dataframe... anything that can hold data will be fine) by functioning on the RDD (the ```dt```), so if the ```map``` function can only change the ```dt``` here, how can I write the data somewhere else?  Again, thank you so much!!!

Comment: You can just give it another name: `new_dt = dt.map(lambda l: 1)`

Comment: Oh! That sounds like a good idea, let me try. Thank you again! You are really so nice!

Comment: It's no problem  :)